# qemu-kvm crash "Resource deadlock avoided"

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

I meet qemu-kvm crash with this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource deadlock avoided
2022-10-10 13:40:53.238+0000: shutting down, reason=crashed
```

HOST OS: **ubuntu 20.04**

/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 --version

```
QEMU emulator version 4.2.1 (Debian 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.23)
Copyright (c) 2003-2019 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

Is there any bug with:

```
qemu-system-x86/focal-updates,focal-security,now 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.23 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

librbd:

```
librbd1/stable,now 16.2.10-1focal amd64 [installed,automatic]
libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd/focal-updates,focal-security,now 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.16 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3-rbd/stable,now 16.2.10-1focal amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

qemu-kvm boot from ceph rdb, will crash.

coredump:

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007f2c2aec3859 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007f2c286f7911 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007f2c2870338c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007f2c28702369 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007f2c28702d21 in __gxx_personality_v0 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007f2c2b0c6bef in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#7  0x00007f2c2b0c7281 in _Unwind_RaiseException () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#8  0x00007f2c2870369c in __cxa_throw () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007f2c286fa73f in std::__throw_system_error(int) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x00007f2c28730060 in std::thread::join() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#11 0x00007f2c28965e14 in ?? () from /lib/librados.so.2
#12 0x00007f2c1b932cb1 in ceph::common::ConfigProxy::set_mon_vals(ceph::common::CephContext*, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<void>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&, std::function<bool (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)>) ()
   from /usr/lib/ceph/libceph-common.so.2
#13 0x00007f2c1b91c3d5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/ceph/libceph-common.so.2
#14 0x00007f2c1b931c85 in boost::asio::detail::strand_service::do_complete(void*, boost::asio::detail::scheduler_operation*, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) ()
   from /usr/lib/ceph/libceph-common.so.2
#15 0x00007f2c28973ca2 in ?? () from /lib/librados.so.2
#16 0x00007f2c2897adea in ?? () from /lib/librados.so.2
#17 0x00007f2c2872fde4 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#18 0x00007f2c2b09b609 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:477
#19 0x00007f2c2afc0133 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

CEPH.CONF

```
[global]

#admin socket = /var/run/ceph/guests/-....asok
auth_cluster_required = cephx
auth_service_required = cephx
auth_client_required = cephx
#public network = 10.3.0.0/24
mon_pg_warn_max_per_osd = 128
mon_max_pg_per_osd = 128
osd_recovery_max_active = 32
osd_max_backfills = 32
osd_op_num_threads_per_shard_hdd = 2
rbd_mirror_concurrent_image_deletions = 2
rbd_op_threads = 4
bluestore_compression_mode = aggressive
osd_pool_default_size = 4
osd_pool_default_min_size = 0
cluster_network = 10.3.0.0/24
#cluster_network_interface = ens255f1
#public_network_interface = ens255f1
[client]
rgw frontends = civetweb port=80
rbd cache = true
rbd cache writethrough until flush = true
#admin socket = /var/run/ceph/guests/-....asok
#log file = /var/log/qemu/qemu-guest-.log
rbd concurrent management ops = 20
osd_op_num_threads_per_shard_hdd = 2
rbd_mirror_concurrent_image_deletions = 2
rbd_op_threads = 4
[osd]
osd_recovery_max_active = 32
osd_max_backfills = 32
osd_op_num_threads_per_shard_hdd = 2
rbd_mirror_concurrent_image_deletions = 2
rbd_op_threads = 4
bluestore_compression_mode = aggressive
[mon]
mon allow pool delete = true
```

Comment: The copy write info you show here tells me this project may have not been updated since 2019. Are you sure it works with this version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you provide additional configuration details? (e.g. what are you trying to run with this happens, resources for your VM, etc)?
@David This version is the latest package for Ubuntu20.

Comment: Ubuntu Core 20?

Comment: vm boot to netboot.xys image as vda and do nothing. @notpeter. Is there any way to generate a coredump when qemu-kvm crash?

Comment: qemu-kvm/focal-updates,focal-security,now 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.23 amd64 [installed,automatic] @David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only occasion I've seen this exact message from QEMU was with weird configuration. Essentially librbd is crashing and with it taking down the whole QEMU process.

Could be a configuration option like `rbd_op_threads` (don't play with this option in production, leave it at the defualt value of `1`).

If it's not that, can you please paste your `ceph.conf`?

Comment: Hi, ceph.conf added. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey, great. Please comment out `rbd_op_threads = 4` completely. This might be your culprit.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, is it need to restart osd.x daemon or ?

Comment: You just need to stop/start (NOT restart) the virtual machines using librbd, so they read the new config.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any way to know how many rbd op thread is the vm using? So that I don't need to wait long time for crash observing.

Comment: Hi, well, when it's more than `1`, your VMs can crash even when you restart ceph-mon, ceph-osd etc.
So if you make your OSDs or monitors restart and the VM doesn't crash, you should be OK.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your tips!

Comment: No problem has it been solved then?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot!